# Handling custom Execption with VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, exception, arabic

I need to handle an exception thrown by SQL with VB.Net. The exception number is larger than 5000, which is why I need to add a custom exception message.

This is the part of sql stored procedure that will throw the exception :

```
IF (@ROWCOUNT <> 1 OR @CURRENT_ROWVERSION <> @RowVersion)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(59003,16,1, 'TCounter')
        GOTO ABORT
    END
```

This is how I built the custom message to SQL:

```
EXEC sp_addmessage 
    @msgnum = 59003, 
    @severity = 16,
    @msgtext = 
        N'someone is working on the same operation right now , please try again in few seconds',
    @lang = 'us_english';

EXEC sp_addmessage 
    @msgnum = 59003, 
    @severity = 16,
    @msgtext = 
        N'يوجد شخص اخر يقوم بنفس العملية في نفس الوقت ,قم بإعادة المحاولة  ',
    @lang = 'arabic';
```

This is the VB.Net code to handle any exception thrown by the Stored Procedure:

```
Try
_vs.UpdateTCounter(_key, tCounter)
Catch ex As Exception
LabelError.Text = ex.Message.ToString()
End Try
```

The problem is that, I am unable to show the Arabic version of the message.

Comment: What do you mean with `not able to show my Arabic version of the message`. Where do you want to show it? Why is this question tagged vb.net?

Comment: im handling a stored procedure with vb.net code , vb execute the stored procedure , and i catch the exception with a try catch like this                                
`code`
 Try
  _vs.UpdateTCounter(_key, tCounter)
catch ex As Exception
 LabelError.Text = ex.Message.ToString()
 End Try
`code`
the default message that shows is the english one , but i need to show the arabic message

Comment: edit your question and show the related vb and sp code

Comment: done thank you ,any idea ?

Comment: where do you set the actual session language?